# Override environment variables via console

Tags: angular

I am looking for a possibility to override that custom value `apiUrl` in the environment via console. I've got a pretty standard setup for my `environment.hmr.ts` which i took from [here](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/enabling-hot-module-replacement-angular-6/). My File looks like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  hmr: true,
  version: {code: 1, name: 'develop'},
  apiUrl: 'http://some-corp.backend.de:1234'
};
```

For serveral reasons i need my own custom backend locally but i do not want to change that environment variable in the .ts file as it is versioned for all other frontend-developers and do not want to commit my changes accidentally.

Is there a way to pass that as an argument during `ng serve ...` WITHOUT altering anything in that `environment.hmr.ts`?

Comment: Create a new environment file, and a new configuration that uses that env file  in `angular.json` file

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that way i'd have to add changes in filesystem wich would be commited to the main repository. in my question i try to avoid any changes in filesystem.